# Android: Error Parsing Large Json on Limited Memory (Specific) Device

Tags: android, json

Using OkHttpClient I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when parsing a 36972 line JSON response on a TC75 (8mb of RAM). The issue occurs when I attempt to call response.body().string()

```
E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 26525298-byte allocation.
```

I have attempted to hold the data in a StringBuilder and a streaming JsonReader as [in this answer here.][1]

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(...).build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(response.body().string()));

    ... (loads of JsonReader parsing)
} catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When running on a Samsung S6 Active (3gb of RAM) the application can parse this JSON easily. How can I avoid this out of memory error with such limited RAM? Is it even possible?

The stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
   Process: com.at.project, PID: 4409
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
      at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:255)
      at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228)
      at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:83)
      at com.at.project.activities.LoginNewActivity$UserLoginTask.getOEMPartPricingJson(LoginNewActivity.java:1496)
      at com.at.project.activities.LoginNewActivity$UserLoginTask.downloadAnyNewJson(LoginNewActivity.java:860)
      at com.at.project.activities.LoginNewActivity$UserLoginTask.checkForatDprojectdates(LoginNewActivity.java:746)
      at com.at.project.activities.LoginNewActivity$UserLoginTask.checkForUpdates(LoginNewActivity.java:659)
      at com.at.project.activities.LoginNewActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginNewActivity.java:486)
      at com.at.project.activities.LoginNewActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginNewActivity.java:465)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please post the complete Java stack trace associated with the code that you have in your question. I can see the `OutOfMemoryError` for the `response.body().string()` scenario. You imply that your `JsonReader` code is not working, but you have not stated what the problem is with that code.

Comment: The JsonReader code has the same issue the StringBuilder code does, which is it runs out of memory on the response.body().string() call. Here is the stack trace.

I will edit the original post with the stack trace.

Comment: Your stack trace shows you calling `string()` on `ResponseBody`. Your source code in your question is *not* calling `string()` on `ResponseBody`. Your source code in your question is calling `charStream()` on `ResponseBody`. Please post the complete Java stack trace **associated with the code that you have in your question, showing your use of `JsonReader` and `charStream()`**.

Comment: Sorry, the charStream() call was a typo. That would throw an error because it returns a Stream in the constructor for a StringReader.

Comment: `ResponseBody` on recent OkHttp versions (e.g., 3.3.1) has `charStream()`. Despite the name, it returns a `Reader`. `JsonReader` takes a `Reader` as input via its constructor. `JsonReader` does not take a `String` as input. So, your earlier code seemed correct, and your now-revised code should not compile.

Comment: Correct again. We had tried to make use of charStream() before posting this question to no avail. Sorry, it was originally a StringReader and has been edited to reflect that.

Comment: I am not terribly surprised that you are getting an `OutOfMemoryError` with `string()` for a JSON file of that size. You are attempting to read the entire JSON file into memory in one block, and that will not work on most devices. Using `charStream()` directly should work better. Hence, you should consider explaining, in detail, what "to no avail" means.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming parsers are designed to return elements of something like XML or json as they are parsed from the stream of data. They will usually allow one to parse large documents with low total memory usage or to cut down buffering time before you can start doing something useful with the file you are parsing.

The [Jackson Streaming](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/) parser is written in java. It may do what you need. I'm sure there are other streaming json parsers out there as well.

For a low memory system, you probably won't be able to suck up all of the data into a String or StringBuilder. Instead, you will hand off the stream to the streaming parser and handle callbacks as elements show up. You'll need to throw out unused and unnecessary elements instead of trying to build a parse tree of the full json file.

Comment: `JsonReader` is a streaming parser, which is what the OP shows in the code in the question.

Comment: The linked code seems to show all of the elements being saved up into a tree. For a low memory system, you'll have to throw out all of the elements you aren't using.  I guess I should make that more clear.

Comment: Evaitl, what do you by mean being saved up into a tree? I am unsure what that would look like in my code.

For what it's worth, the device runs out of memory by just accessing the stream in the line
    
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(response.body().string()));

Comment: I think the code has changed. Most parsers create a full parse tree of whatever is being parsed. For low memory systems with a streaming parser, you register callbacks that get called when the elements you are interested show up in the parse stream. You do what you need with those elements and toss everything else.   There is an example [Parse JSON Response with Gson](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) that passes the okhttp response stream to a json parser instead of trying to suck up the whole response and pass a string to the parser. It sounds like you'll need to do that.

Comment: Thank you evaitl, I will try this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The memory error is related to the maximum amount of memory that your variable can have.

I recommend use and JSON to POJO helper, which will store the data directly in Objects, who have a larger heap of memory.

It's very simple to work with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) libs.

You can also use a HTTP Helper to do the request more easily, the most of them already use GSON and Jackson to deserialize.

I use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), but [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) is a good alternative too.

I know that not resolve your error, but i think is much more easier implement those libraries than optimize by your own the memory use and http requests.